# Setting up WAMP onWin 7 - having issues with 'localhost'

Tags: localhost, iis-7.5, wamp, dreamweaver

I don't know anything about this stuff so bear with me. After 3 hours I finally got the WAMP 'green light' by changing the port (in the files httpd.conf, wampmanager.tpl & wampmanager.ini)  to use localhost:8080 (I had tried to disable IIS 7.5 with no luck, I kept getting 'port 80 used by IIS', and yes I changed the setting in Skype and then ended up totally uninstalling it).

When I go to 'localhost' I see a list of everything in inetpub/wwwroot.

When I go to 'localhost:8080' I get the WAMP screen.

I copied a php (non database) website into the wamp/www folder, named the folder 'websitename' (with an index.php file in it).  When I go to http://localhost:8080 and get the WAMP screen, and click on the project 'websitename' I get this in the browser address bar:

```
"http://search.centurylink.com/index.php?origURL=http%3A//websitename/&r=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/&bc="
```

So I then did a search to trouble shoot that and found/did this:

```
    Open index.php in www folder and set

change line 30:$suppress_localhost = true;

to $suppress_localhost = false;

This will ensure the project is prefixed with your local host IP/name
```

When I did that, now when I go to 'localhost:8080/websitename' I get "Internal Server Error".

Then I tried to set up a virtual host using these instructions:

```
The WAMP user menu

When you select the httpd.conf entry, Notepad will open with the contents of the httpd.conf file. Within this file, you need to uncomment out the entry for virtual hosts configuration file location. Search for these two lines:

# Virtual hosts
# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Remove the "#" in the second line above and save and close the httpd.conf file.

httpd-vhosts.conf
The next file to edit cannot be accessed through the WAMP user interface; you should find this file in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache-XXX\conf\extra\ (XXX is the release number). Open that file in Notepad and add the following section (we're sticking with our current example of "mysite").

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin emailaddress@domain.com
DocumentRoot "c:\MYSITE"
ServerName mysite.local
ErrorLog "logs/mysite.log"
CustomLog "logs/mysite-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I use Dreamweaver to manage about 150 websites (some html, some php as well as WordPress). How do I get a site to open when I use F12?  Right now I get this link this link in the address bar:

```
'http://localhost:8080/websitename/index.php'
```

Which says: "Internal Server Error"

I also do not understand the relationship between Dreamweaver and the files that are in the inetpub/wwwroot and the files that should/would be in the wamp/www folder. I have tried setting up a testing server both with a website in a folder within the inetpub/wwwroot folder and also in the wamp/www folder.  Both give the same results (Internal Server Error).

These are the setting I'm using within Dreamweaver for the testing server settings:

```
Connection Using: Local/Network
ServerFolder:  C:\wamp\www\websitename
Web URL: http://localhost:8080/websitename/
```

Once I get the 'localhost' issue sorted will I have to move all my website files from inetpub/wwwroot to wamp/www?

Thank you so much. :)

Comment: have you created 'websitename' virtual host or a folder inside the root?

Comment: I created a folder named 'websitename' within the wamp/www folder.

I know nothing about virtual hosts... but now I'm listening.  :)

Comment: if its a folder then you can access it by visiting http://localhost:8080/websitename

Comment: Lucky Chingi - as I wrote above:

"when I go to 'localhost:8080/websitename' I get "Internal Server Error"."